# Kotlin: Make the BottomNavigationBar highlights the correct active fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

First of all, sorry for my question. I am still learning the basics.
I followed a tutorial on how to create a BottomNavigationBar. It basically makes the "FragmentA" reads an EditText and sends the String to "FragmentB". However, there is a problem that I am unable to solve: when the "FragmentB" is shown, the BottomNavigationBar still highlights the button of "FragmentA". How can I always show the correct fragment on the NavBar? Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McQTc.png)

```
enter code here
```

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Communicator {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val fragmentA = FragmentA()
    val fragmentB = FragmentB()
    val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)

    setCurrentFragment(fragmentA) // sets fragmentA as default

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.fragmentA->setCurrentFragment(fragmentA)
            R.id.fragmentB->setCurrentFragment(fragmentB)
        }
        true
    }
}

// FragmentA send message to FragmentB
override fun passDataString(editTextInput: String) {
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("message", editTextInput)
    val fragmentB = FragmentB()
    fragmentB.arguments = bundle
    setCurrentFragment(fragmentB)
}

// set the current fragment
private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment:Fragment)=
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
        commit()
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could open new project and select Bottom Navigation Activity to understand how it's work.

[image]